# Kenneth Rosen - Discrete Math (product rule and truth table) - Section 6.1 n. 70

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

I was trying to solve an exercise from Kenneth Rosen - Discrete Math's book. The exercise is the following, and it involves using the product rule:

> Use the product rule to show that there are $2^{2^{n}}$ different truth tables for propositions in $n$ variables.

The solution should be something like this:

We know that since there are two possible ways of assigning a truth value to a propositional variable, given $n$ propositional variables there are $2^{n}$ possible different assignment of truth values.

Then we can ask ourselves how many different truth table can be built starting from those different assignment.

A  truth table can be thought of as a function that takes as argument an assignment of truth values and gives as output another truth value.

For instance, one truth table for $p,q,r$ can be considered as the function $t1$ that goes from the set of possible assignment for $p,q,r$ of cardinality 8 to the set ${T,F}$ and it is that function that always assign $T$ and never $F$. A different truth table of the same variables could be the funciton $t2$ that for every possible assignment of truth value to $p,q,r$ it always assign $T$ unless $p$ is false, and so on.

So each truth table corresponds to a function from the set of possible different assignment to the set of boolean values ${T,F}$.

Since we know that the set of possible assignment for $n$ propositional variables has cardinality $2^{n}$ and the codomain of the truth table functions is of cardinality $2$,then there are $2^{2^{n}}$ possibile ways of building truth tables for $n$ variables.

Is it correct to consider truth table for $n$ variables as functions that go from the set of possible assignment to the set ${T,F}$)

Comment: Did you mean to say is it correct to consider propositions in $n$ variables as functions that go from the set of possible truth assignments to the set $\{T, F\}$?

Answer (score 1):

In a proposition with $n$ variables, each of the $n$ variables can be assigned one of two truth values, so there are $2^n$ ways to assign truth values for those $n$ variables.  Each of these $2^n$ choices corresponds to a different hypothesis.  There are two possible truth values for the conclusion of the proposition which could be assigned to each hypothesis.  Hence, there are $2^{2n}$ ways to construct a truth table for propositions in $n$ variables.

A proposition can be viewed as a function from the set of possible truth assignments for the $n$ variables to the set $\{T, F\}$ of possible truth values for the conclusion.